# Координатная сетка

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать сетку в прямоугольном блоке-квадратными блоками 40х40px, но у меня блоки выходят из прямоугольной области, как правильно сделать?

<div style="width:1188px;height:343px;border:1px solid green;">
<?php
$number = (1188*343)/(40*40);

for ($x=0; $x<=$number; $x++)
     {
        ?>
        <div style="width:40px;height:40px;border:1px solid red;float:left;"></div>
        <?
     }
?>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div style="width:1188px;height:343px;border:1px solid green;overflow:hidden">`

[overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)